# Digital to Analog Conversion with STM32F7 Discovery Board

Tags: stm32, dac, nucleo, stm32f7

I am a mechanical engineer interested in Data Acquisition and Closed-Loop Control projects. As a beginner who wants to work with STM32 microcontrollers, I have a specific question about the STM32F7 DISCOVERY board: How can I perform Digital to Analog Conversion (DAC) using STM32F7 DISCOVERY board.

According to the user manual, the PA4 and PA5 pins of the STM32F746NG microcontroller are dedicated to High Speed USB and DCMI Camera connector. These pins are not directly available to the user (such as in Nucleo-F746ZG, in which the PA4 and PA5 pins are directly accessible through the morpho connectors). Do I need an extra board to perform DAC with STM32F7 DISCOVERY board?

What should I do to access the PA4 / PA5 pins for DAC operations that are essentially required in closed-loop control projects?
Regards
Mohsen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need an extra board to perform DAC with STM32F7 DISCOVERY board

Yes, PA4 and PA5 are not accessible (which is weird that they would not make them accessible )

> What should I do to access the PA4 / PA5 pins for DAC operations that
>   are essentially required in closed-loop control projects?

The DAC probably isn't the best for control as it is only 12-bit and 3.3V. The STM32F7NG also doesn't have a lot of 0.1" headers, it is more of a minicomputer board. You *could* find [PA4/PA5 on the board and hack into them](https://keilpack.azureedge.net/content/Keil.STM32F7xx_DFP.2.11.0/MDK/Boards/ST/STM32F746G_Discovery/Documentation/DM00190424.pdf), at the same time it would probably disable the high speed USB because those lines need to be impedance matched.

I would suggest a 16-bit spi dac: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=sparkfun+16bit+dac

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Does your solution guarantees high sample rates (10 KHz or higher) for analog output (DAC) operations? What if I use another board like Nucleo-F746ZG (144pins) that provides direct access to PA4 / PA5 pins?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: Yes, if you ensure that you buy a dac can sample that fast

Comment: Unlike 32F746G DISCOVERY board, I wonder which of the following boards can provide DAC (Digital to Analog Conversion) pins for the user : a) 32F429I DISCOVERY board (with STM32429ZIT6 microcontroller) b) 32F469I DISCOVERY board (with STMF469NIHI microcontroller) ???